# Iterate over a list by setting element as a variable

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I would like to create 12 dataframes labelled with month names by using a `for` loop. So I created a list with the month names `list_month`. But I am not able to insert the variable `i` as `df_[i]` in the `for` loop.

The operation I am trying to do is to create a new dataframe `df_new_month` like `df_new_feb = df_feb[df_feb['my_feature'] > 20]` for each month contained in the list:

Should I follow a different approach?

```py
list_month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
for i in list_month:
    df_new_[i] = df_[i][df_[i]['my_feature'] > 20]
    print(i, list_month[i])
```

The Error I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call 
  last):File"/Users/annalisa/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site_ 
  packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3325, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-50-c09b1f63eb51>", line 3, in <module>
    df_new_[i] = df_[i][df_[i]['my_feature'] > 20]
NameError: name 'df_' is not defined
```

Comment: Show the error message. How does `df_` look like? What is `df_[i][df_[i]` supposed to do? `i` is a string containing the name of the month. `list_month[i]` is meaningless. What do you want to do?

Comment: Could the dataframes be `df_jan`, `df_feb`, and so on?

Comment: to create  `df_new_jan`, `df_new_feb`, etc. you have to do it manually, not in loop. With loop you can create dictionary with `df_new_["jan"]`,  `df_new_["feb"]`. OR  you would have to use methods which are not preferred. Besides dictionary with  `df_new_["jan"]`,  `df_new_["feb"]` can be more useful then separated variables `df_new_jan`, `df_new_feb`

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should keep all in dictionary and then you will have no problems - `df["new_feb"] = df["feb"][ df["feb"]['my_feature'] > 20 ]`

Comment: Thanks everyone, could you tell me please why did you put a -1 to my post? Thanks

Comment: @SergeBallesta yes, they have to be.

Comment: @furas I posted the comment error

Comment: I putted -1 becuase you didn't put full error message at start and full error is always very important element.

Comment: @furas The full error is not ALWAYS very important: it is not a post requirement and is not a determinant for experts. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207985/discussion-between-annalix-and-furas).

Comment: @Annalix mostly is very important. it shows exaclty what code you run, exactly what error you get. You can also often see what version of Python you run, and what system you use (i guess Mac because path starts with /Users/). Your eror also shows that you use `ipython` and `anaconda`. And all this information can be important to resolve problem. You never know what we will need so better show it.

Comment: @furas yes, we are everyone aware about how could be important the error message. However, the -1 is not justified as to post the message error is not a requirement, it is not essential, actually many expert are able to answer without error message. Moreover, by simply asking in a comment it can be inserted in the post as I did. 

Therefore, please could you remove the -1 to my post. There are too many -1. I also notice that you didn't provide any solution to the post but only 'negative contribution' to others' efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather *hackish* but should work, given that I understood you correctly:

```
list_month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
for i in list_month:
    exec("df_new_{month} = df_{month}[df_{month}['my_feature'] > 20]".format(month=i))
```

Basically it will create a string looking the way you would type it in your script and execute it.

But maybe you should re-think and rather put the data into the same DataFrame like

```
df_feb['new'] = ...
```

Comment: @Annalix maybe it resolves your problem but `exec()` is not preferred method. Preferred is to use dictionary `df_new_["jan"], df_new_["feb"]` instead of separated variable. Now you will may have to use the same *hackish* methods to work with separated variable. With dictionary you don't need any *hackish* method.

Comment: @furas I got it. For now it is working and to create df with dictionary like suggests is not convenient either.

Answer (score -3):

In my opinion you have to define at first the variable (`df_`) and then go with your `for` loop.
For example at least :

```py
df_ = 0 
list_month = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may','jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec']
for i in list_month:
    df_[i] = df_[i][df_[i]['my_feature'] > 20]
    print(i, list_month[i])
```

Comment: Hey Toni, thanks for contributing to StackOverflow. Don't let those downvotes discourage you from taking part in this community in the future, but rather take them as incentive to writing great answers in the future. I am certainly no StackOverflow veteran, but I feel like I can give you a few hints, though. Always make sure to [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) your answer in an appealing and easy to read manner (this means using code fences e.g.)...

Comment: ...but more importantly, think twice before answering whether you completely understood the question and can provide a solution. Read more about writing good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).
To those who downvoted: Considering Toni's a new contributor could some of you maybe give a quick explanation on what you're reasons were?